# Select rows that have matching values in three columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pull the rows that have three matching columns: the employee, new date, and original date. I need to see if an employee has had multiple changes (rows) on the same date.

Input:

| EmployeeName | EditDate | NewDate | OriginalDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gonzales, Dave | 2/1/21 9:42 AM | 1/31/21 | NULL |
| Gonzales, Dave | 2/4/21 8:31 AM | NULL | 1/31/21 |
| Gonzales, Dave | 2/4/21 8:32 AM | NULL | 1/31/21 |
| Smith, Matthew | 1/11/21 11:46 AM | 1/8/21 | NULL |
| Smith, Matthew | 1/26/21 2:18 PM | 1/14/21 | NULL |
| Smith, Matthew | 1/26/21 2:18 PM | NULL | 1/14/21 |
| Terry, Jennifer | 3/26/21 10:54 AM | 3/24/21 | NULL |
| Vincent, Jim | 2/5/21 11:54 AM | 2/3/21 | NULL |
| Vincent, Jim | 2/8/21 9:12 AM | 2/3/21 | NULL |
| Vincent, Jim | 2/5/21 11:50 AM | NULL | 2/4/21 |
| Vincent, Jim | 2/18/21 10:19 AM | NULL | 2/18/21 |

Desired output:

| EmployeeName | EditDate | NewDate | OriginalDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gonzales, Dave | 2/1/21 9:42 AM | 1/31/21 | NULL |
| Gonzales, Dave | 2/4/21 8:31 AM | NULL | 1/31/21 |
| Gonzales, Dave | 2/4/21 8:32 AM | NULL | 1/31/21 |
| Smith, Matthew | 1/26/21 2:18 PM | 1/14/21 | NULL |
| Smith, Matthew | 1/26/21 2:18 PM | NULL | 1/14/21 |

I tried code below but no luck.

```
df = df.groupby(['NewDate', 'OriginalDate']).reset_index()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It would also be helpful for you to post the result of what you tried - did it give you an error?  Did it give you incorrect results?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
df = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['EmployeeName','NewDate','OriginalDate'], keep='first')]
```

refer to this link for detailed info https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the "pandasql" library. It allows you to use SQL code to manipulate the data. Here, the pandas data frame would be the table.

```
import pandasql as psql

result = psql.sqldf('''
SELECT *
FROM df''')
```